# How to allow user to download private document in Scribd

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, scribd

I would like to ask for any suggestion on how to implement PDF download with private document in Scribd.

Code to upload the document with Scribd using PHP.

```
function allowPdf($doc_ids) {
    $method = "docs.changeSettings";
    $params['doc_ids'] = $doc_ids;
    $params['access'] = 'private';
    $params['download_formats'] = 'pdf';
    $params['disable_select_text'] = 1;

    // Method from Scribd Developer
    // http://www.scribd.com/clients/scribd_php_client.zip    
    $result = $this->postRequest($method, $params); 

    return $result;
}
```

In the Front End code to render out the Scribd JS.

```
function renderScribdDoc(doc_id, access_key, id) {
    id = id || 'embedded_doc';
    var scribd_doc = scribd.Document.getDoc(doc_id, access_key),
        onDocReady = function(e) {};

    scribd_doc.addParam('jsapi_version', 2);
    scribd_doc.addParam('hide_disabled_buttons', false);
    scribd_doc.addParam('public', true);
    scribd_doc.addParam('width', 520);
    scribd_doc.addParam('height', 390);
    scribd_doc.addEventListener('docReady', onDocReady);
    scribd_doc.write(id);
}
```

I don't know what is the correct way to pass the parameter in Scribd to allow user to download private document as PDF.

Thank you very much.